# Transact SQL, prefix with schema or not?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm developing a tool where I've prefixed tables etc. with "dbo" now I get requests for custom schema names. I'm thinking of skipping them and instead let the user control this via the associated login against the Db. I know there's talk about "performance" since it needs to search the users's schemes and then fallback on dbo etc, but is that really an issue? Opinions?

Answer (score 1):

First, I would look at this question as a feature request from your customers (users?). So the immediate decision to make is, should you even consider looking into this now, or do you have other feature requests that are obviously more important and deliver more benefit to the customer?

For example, for now you could simply tell customers that your application requires its own database that should not be shared with other applications or manipulated in any way by the customer. Then you don't have to worry about schemas or the same object name in two schemas because your application 'owns' the database. Perhaps this is already the case, but if so then I don't understand why your customers care which schema your objects are in.

Second, assuming that you do decide to work on it, you should gather some information about why people are asking for this, to make sure that you clearly understand what they expect you to deliver and what the benefit is for them. If customers are really saying "your application runs slowly" then the choice of schema is highly unlikely to be the reason, it's much more probable that indexing, schema design or your application code are the areas to look at.

Finally, if you still want to go ahead you need to find a technical solution. This is partly a deployment issue and partly a coding issue. It's a deployment issue because you have to deploy your database objects in a specific schema that is specified at installation time, and all your patches and later releases need to be aware of that too. The coding issue is that you need your database code to be "schema-aware", in case you end up in a situation where you have `dbo.TableName`, `MyTool.TableName` and `OtherSchema.TableName` all in the same database. The solution is obviously to reference the schema name in all code, which is considered an [important best practice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283095.aspx) anyway. But exactly how you do this depends on how you have structured your application, if you use an ORM etc.